# Laravel slective Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I am just building my first Laravel App and have the following question:

Simplified Table Structure:

Table CORPORATE

- id pk
- name
- checkbox "isSupplier"
- checkbox "isManufacturer"

Table COMPONENT

- id pk
- name
- if_corporate fk (where isManufacturer=true)

So my question is, where do I need to put hands on the code to get this "selector" implemented?

Thanks

edit:

**resources/views/admin/components/create.blade.php**

```
<select class="form-control select2 {{ $errors->has('corp') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="corp_id" id="corp_id" required>
    @foreach($corps as $id => $corp)
        <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('corp_id') == $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $corp }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

is this the correct place to modify?

Comment: what are you looking after ? the relationship code in the model ? the route + controller code ? the front html/js code ? or all of them ?

Comment: What have you tried to implement already? Can you show what code you've created but need help with?

Comment: I am using quickAdminPanel to create base code, this is giving me a basic working set of code. However, if you create a new "COMPONENT" in my model, you can link that to any item in "CORPORATE" but I want limit the content of the drop-down to the subset of "CORPORATES" with the property isManufacturer checked. Does that make sense?

Comment: sorry, new to StackOverflow ... I added some extra info to my question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already too late in the code you have shared. That is the **view**, which comes after the **controller** in this instance.

The controller is probably called something like `ComponentsController` there will be a line of code that says

```
$corps = Corporates::all();
```

Or something like that. That is where you need to update it. Probably something like this:

```
$corps = Corporates::where(["isManufacturer" => true)->get();
```

Now `$corps` will be a collection of only ones that are manufacturers.